# $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=0$ and Elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

What is relation between $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=0$ and Elliptic curves?

Comment: If you really don't know, you better ask this on Mathstackexchange.

Comment: An elliptic curve is a smooth projective curve of genus one with at least one rational point. So the above two answers are enough to illuminate the relation you want.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, the map given by achille hui gives a 3-to-1 map from your curve $C$ to the elliptic curve $E$ that he lists, so although it is true that every point in $C(\mathbb{Q})$ gives a rational point in $E(\mathbb{Q})$, the converse is not true, at least, not via the map that he gives. The way to really understand your curve is that it is a homogeneous space of degree 3 for the elliptic curve $E$. You'll find homogeneous spaces described in Chapter X of my book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* (Springer). There is a long, influential article of Selmer [1] in which he makes a detailed study of your curves, and in particular finds a large number of them that have $p$-adic points for all $p$, but no $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points. In modern terminology, they correspond to elements of order 3 in the Shafarevich-Tate group of $E$.

[1] E. Selmer, The {D}iophantine equation $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=0$,
*Acta Math.* **85** (1951), 203-362.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, prof. Silverman!

Comment: @Joe Silverman. Could you tell me how to see $C: 3x^3+4Y^3+5Z^3=0$ as $E/\Bbb{Q}: X^3+Y^3+60Z^3=0$-torsor ? If we find an isomorphism $\phi: C \cong E$ over $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$, we can define a morphism $\mu$ over $\Bbb{Q}$  , $\mu : E\times C \to C$ by $(p,P)\mapsto  {\phi}^{-1}(p+\phi(P))$. This induces simply transitive action on the points over $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$. But I cannot find this map $\phi$ for years. I tried, for example, $(X,Y,Z)\mapsto (4X,4(3/4)^{1/3},(4/3)^{2/3}, (4/3)^{2/3}Z))$, but  $\mu$ is not defined over $\Bbb{Q}$ according to Desboces's formula.

Comment: I asked on this page and received a comment, but the $\phi$ in the comment does not provide the $\mu$ that is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. I have been searching for a long time for this isomorphism map $\phi$. I would like to hear your opinion on what this map $\phi$ is, Professor. (cf. [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633815/how-elliptic-curve-e-bbbq-x3y360z3-0-acts-simply-transitively-on-c](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633815/how-elliptic-curve-e-bbbq-x3y360z3-0-acts-simply-transitively-on-c))

Answer (score 10):

Consider the map
$$(x,y,z)\quad\mapsto\quad (X,Y) = \left(  \frac{-4bcyz}{x^2}, \frac{-4bc(by^3-cz^3)}{x^3} \right)$$
By brute force expansion, one can verify
$$Y^2 - X^3 - (4abc)^2 =
\frac{16 b^2c^2(-ax^3+by^3+cz^3)(ax^3+by^3+cz^3)}{x^6}
$$
This means every non-zero integer solution of 
$\quad\displaystyle a x^3 + b y^3 + c z^3 = 0\quad$
corresponds to a rational point on the elliptic curve 
$$Y^2 = X^3 + (4abc)^2$$

Answer (score 6):

Furthermore, the correspondence point out by Hui implies that if $ax^3+by^3+cz^3 = N$ has a rational solution, then one can generally find an infinite more.  This can be proven by the identity,
$$ap^3+bq^3+cr^3 = (ax^3+by^3+cz^3)(ax^3-by^3)^3$$
where,
$$p,\,q,\,r = x(ax^3+2by^3),\; -y(2ax^3+by^3),\;  z(ax^3-by^3) $$
For example, this shows that,
$$x^3+y^3 = 9$$
has an infinite number of rational solutions.

For more, see Form 19 at http://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/011.