# Are there an infinite number of positive rational solutions to $x^3+y^3=19$?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

By transforming the equation to Weierstrass form, I have established that the rational solutions to $x^3+y^3=19$ can be constructed by two generators of the elliptic curve group: $(3,-2)$ and $(\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2})$ , and that the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$

However, I can't see how to establish whether there are an infinite number of solutions where $x$ and $y$ are both positive rational numbers.

Comment: I don't know how to do it formally correct, but there is a pretty nice intuition why there are infinitely many. If you plot the graph of this function you see that there is a part of it that is in the upper left quadrant ($x,y \geq 0$). You know that there is one point in this quadrant. Every rational line through that point that intersects the curve, will intersect the curve at a rational point(this fact is easy to see algebraically). As there are infinitely many such rational lines that intersect the curve in the upper left quadrant, there are infinitely many rational solutions greater $0$.

Comment: Maybe you can somehow formalise this idea, by showing that one such line exists and then arguing that there are infinitely many that intersect in an open subset around the intersection point. I made this a comment, because it's not a formal solution.

Comment: It isn't always true that a rational line through a rational point on the curve intersects at another rational point. For example, consider the point on the curve $(\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2})$ and the line $3x+5y=15$. This intersects the curve at two non-rational points, as shown in https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2By%5E3%3D19%2C++3x%2B5y%3D15

Comment: If you can show there are infinitely many such solutions with increasing large $x$, you are done, for when $x > 895/196$, the third point of intersection between that point and $(5/2, 3/2)$ lies in the first quadrant (geometrically).

Comment: $x^3+y^3=19$ can be transformed to elliptic curve $Y^2=X^3-432\cdot19^2$ with $(x,y) = (\frac{684+Y}{6X},\frac{684-Y}{6X}).$
If $|Y| < 684$ then $(x,y)$ is positive rational solution.
Since this curve has infinitely many rational points, I guess there are infinitely many rational points such as $|Y|<684.$

Comment: See the comments under [this old related answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225511/11619). When an elliptic curve has a positive rank, the rational points are dense in any component of the real locus that has at least one rational point.

Comment: Arthur Vause, your example with the point $(5/2,3/2)$ and the line is not in the spirit of the chord-tangent method for generating more rational points. If you begin with a single point, you need to start with the tangent of the curve at that point to be guaranteed that the third point of intersection has rational coordinates. The chord works if you have two distinct rational points. See the linked answer for a few examples.

Comment: (cont'd) The method you described *fix a point with rational coordinates and consider lines via that point with a rational slope* does not work for genus $>0$ curves. If it did, we would get a parametrization of the points by rational functions, and those can only exist when genus is zero. The parametrization of Pythagorean triples is a well known case (and the circle has $g=0$). Another is the singular cubic curve known as the folium (of Descartes). Its singularity makes it a genus zero curve in spite of it being a cubic.

Comment: Jyrki Lahtonen, thanks for your reply. My example of a rational line through a point on the curve was simply presented as a counterexample to Guenterino's assertion that every rational line through a rational point on the curve that intersects the curve, will intersect the curve at a rational point.

Comment: Sorry, Arthur. I missed that. Should have read more carefully and adress the comment @Guenterino instead.

Comment: Do you know of a proof of user670344's statement in another post that if the rank is at least one, then the rational points are dense on any connected component with at least one rational point ?

Comment: @ArthurVause I think it goes as follows. The real locus is a compact space (w.r.t. the topology it inherits from the real projective space. Any connected component is homeomorphic to $S^1$. An infinite subgroup thus has an accumulation point somewhere. I think it necessarily has one at the neutral element also. Hence by continuity of the group operation every point of that subgroup is an accumulation point etc.

Comment: (cont'd) It may be easier to see the argument go via the model $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$ of the elliptic curve though I'm not sure what the preimage of the real points looks like. Anyway, if the preimage looks like "a line", it is easy to believe that modulo the lattice any point of infinite order generates a dense subset.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments from @rogerl and @JyrkiLahtonen, I think I can answer the question.

As the group of rational points on the curve is infinite, it has an accumulation point, either at a finite point on the curve, or at infinity.

If there is an accumulation point at infinity, i.e. there are infinitely many such solutions with increasing large $x$, then the point of intersection (point B in the diagram) of lines joining these points with $(\frac{5}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$ lies on the curve between $(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{2})$ and $(\frac{5}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$, and therefore has positive $x$ and $y$

[image]

If there is a finite accumulation point, point C on the diagram, construct the point D as the intersection of the curve with the line joining C to $(\frac{5}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$.

Then there are infinitely many points sufficiently close to C (e.g. F and G) where the  curve and the lines FD or GD intersect the curve at a point close to $(\frac{5}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$, i.e. a point with positive $x$ and $y$

[image]

Edit 26 Jul 2021

A more satisfactory proof that for an elliptic curve of rank at least 1, there are inﬁnitely many rational solutions in every neighbourhood of any one of them is provided by Zachary Scherr, The real topology of rational points on elliptic curves, 2012, [http://eg.bucknell.edu/~zls002/papers/rationalpoints.pdf](http://eg.bucknell.edu/%7Ezls002/papers/rationalpoints.pdf)