# How elliptic curve $E/ \Bbb{Q}: X^3+Y^3+60Z^3=0$ acts simply transitively on $C/ \Bbb{Q}: 3X^3+4Y^3+5Z^3=0$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-actions, arithmetic-geometry

Selmer curve $C/ \Bbb{Q}: 3X^3+4Y^3+5Z^3=0$ is known to be a torsor of elliptic curve $E/ \Bbb{Q}: X^3+Y^3+60Z^3=0$.
Here, $C$ is torsor of $E$ if only if $E$ acts simply transitively on $C$.

How $E$ acts on $C$? In other words, what is the map $E×C→C$ ?

My try : $E$ is Jacobia variety of $C$, so there is unique Abel Jacobi map $φ:C→E$. Let consider the map $E×C→C$ given by $φ^{-1}(φ(P)+Q)$, where '+' means addition of elliptic curve $E$.. This is well defined, but I cannot prove the transitivity.

Comment: I would try the isomorphism defined over $\Bbb{Q}((3/4)^{1/3}), f:[x:y:z]\mapsto [3(4/3)^{1/3} x:4 (3/4)^{1/3}y:z]$. The group law with $O=[1:-1:0]$ on $E$ gives a group law $g:C\times C\to C$ with $g(f(.),.)$ maybe defined over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Your edit is confused (you didn't define $\varphi$ and $+$). Is my $g(f(.),.)$ defined over $\Bbb{Q}$?